# Magento get price including tax in a none-template file

Tags: php, magento, get

At the moment i am trying to get the product price including tax in a php file for my product feed. I have this code at the moment:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$_priceIncludingTax = $this->helper('tax')
                               ->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
```

Problem is that since that of course the '$this->' part doesn't work so well from the file.
Anyone know how i can still get the price including tax in this file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get a helper-instance in any file using:

```
Mage::helper('tax')
```

Your full code is:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')
    ->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
```

Comment: How to get this in magento2?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Alex:

If the product has FinalPrice special price is the final price of the product to access the most serious tax base price:

```
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p->getId());

    $_specialPriceIncTax = Mage::helper('tax')
        ->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());

    $_priceTax = Mage::helper('tax')
        ->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice());
```