# In Magento how to get the regular price of each product that include tax in the shopping cart?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I use this line to get the regular price of the product item in the shopping cart,

```
$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProduct()->getPrice());
```

But I actually want to get the regular price **include the tax**, any idea how I can get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_item->getProduct(), $_item->getProduct()->getPrice());
```

See also [Magento get price including tax in a none-template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287820/magento-get-price-including-tax-in-a-none-template-file)